# daloRadius Is not working, DB.PHP file not found

Tags: php, database, open-source

**daloRadius** is an open source and free software based on **php**, i downloaded it and trying to run it in **waamp server**, after the login page i am getting this error

***include_once(DB.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\daloradius-0.9-9\library\opendb.php***

I have searched thoroughly the db.php file but couldnt find it in the folder, what should I do? Do Ii have to create the file?

Comment: its tell you dont have file. In short you need that file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the PHP Pear DB library. Install the library via `pear install DB`

Comment: Thankyou so much,I appreciate your answer and i have installed it, but now the problem is that it says that pear.php is missing, and i searched again and it is not in the folder any where

Comment: Seems that you are missing the Pear extension. You will need to install the Pear base in order for everything to work.

Answer (score 5):

I was working on a ubuntu 14 based freeradius setup and daloradius as web interface, encountered the same issue.

> PHP Warning:  include_once(DB.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in /var/www/html/daloradius/library/opendb.php on
>   line 84

Installing `php-db` worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install php-db
```